# How to target DOM and change style in react with mapped elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

I have a multi page form that renders a list of buttons for each possible answer.

I am currently using getElementByID to change the button style when a button is clicked. I think this is not considered good practice in react.

can I use the useRef hook to target the DOM element and change its style instead of using getElementByID if the buttons are dynamically displayed with map?

```
{answers.map((answer, count = 0) => {
        return (
          <Button
            key={count}
            id=`button${count}`
            onClick={(e) => {        
              document.getElementById(`${e.currentTarget.id}`).style.color = "white";
            }}
          >
            <ButtonTitle>{answer.name}</ButtonTitle>
          </Button>
        );
      })}
```

(animations on safari are breaking the active style, so I can't use the active pseudo element)

Comment: React uses VirtualDOM for updating DOM, so it is not a good idea to update a DOM manually instead of react hooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a new state and toggle `active` class by that state.
Code something like this.

```
const [activeindex, setActiveIndex] = useState("");

return(
<>
{answers.map((answer, count = 0) => {
        return (
          <Button
            key={count}
            className={count==activeindex?"acvie":""}
            onClick={(e) => {        
              setActiveIndex(count)
            }}
          >
            <ButtonTitle>{answer.name}</ButtonTitle>
          </Button>
        );
      })}
}
</>
```

And use .active class in css file.